# TCL, get full error message in catch command

Tags: error-handling, tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh     

proc test {} {
    aaa
}

test
```

When I run this script I get error message:

```
invalid command name "aaa"
    while executing
"aaa"
    (procedure "test" line 2)
    invoked from within
"test"
    (file "./a.tcl" line 7)
```

If I run test command in `catch` I get only first line of error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc test {} {
    aaa
}

catch test msg
puts $msg
```

This prints:
`invalid command name "aaa"`

Is it possible to get full error message (file, line, procedure) in catch command? My program has many files and by getting just one line of error message it is difficult to find from where is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to look at the value of `errorInfo` which will contain the stack trace.

The more complete  answer is to look at the [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm) and the [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm) manual pages and make use of the `-optionsVarName` parameter to the `catch` statement to collect the more detailed information provided. The `return` manual page gives some information on using this. But a rough example from an interactive session:

```
% proc a {} { catch {funky} err detail; return $detail }
% a
-code 1 -level 0 -errorstack {INNER {invokeStk1 funky} CALL a} -errorcode NONE -errorinfo {invalid command name "funky"
    while executing
"funky"} -errorline 1
%
```

The `detail` variable is a dictionary, so use `dict get $detail -errorinfo` to get that particular item.