# Why does TCL CATCH command not return an error?

Tags: error-handling, tcl

I am attempting to launch a compiled code to handle the extensive computing needed by a TCL script I am writing. When I launch the code, I am using:

```
if {[catch {exec $cwd/TaubinSmoother &} error_out]} {
    if {[string first "couldn" $error_out] != -1} {
        puts "TaubinSmoother software could not be located."
        exit
    } else {
        puts "$error_out"
    }
}
```

When the `exec` command executes, there appears to be no error, but one is indeed generated because the PATH environment is not properly set for shared libraries that *TaubinSmoother* needs in order to run. I have tried using:

```
 proc launch {} {
     set error_catch [catch {exec $cwd/TaubinSmoother &} error_out detail]
     return $detail
 }

 set cwd       [file dirname [info script]]
 set error_out launch
 puts "$error_out"
```

This too did not work as I only received a "launch" printed to the stdout. I read [TCL, get full error message in catch command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212736/tcl-get-full-error-message-in-catch-command) and more about [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm) and [return](http://www.tcl.tk/http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htmman/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm), but the answered question did not work in my case and the examples on the man-pages did not help. How do I get the actual error to return to my running script so I can warn future users of the issues encountered?

Answer (score 3):

## Problem 1

Your second attempt fails in the sense of "not meeting your expectation" because the line

```
 set error_out launch
```

should read

```
 set error_out [launch]
```

Background: in its original form, it is an assignment of a literal string "launch" to a variable `error_out`. Hence, this is what you see printed.

## Problem 2

Your `exec` runs in background mode (`&`). Therefore, your Tcl script is not correlated with the backgrounded process any longer. `exec` will just return without signalling any (well, background) error. Better use a bullet-proven Tcl idiom for checking on a background process, using `open` and `fileevent`:

See [Detect end of TCL background process in a TCL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112376/detect-end-of-tcl-background-process-in-a-tcl-script)